# Python: How to calculate revenue which is generated by month between years?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

The columns in the below dataset will have:

A: Date contract opened;

B: Date contract stops;

C: Unique account ID against which contract associated (can have multiple contracts live against one ID)

D: Monthly revenue for contract period - for simplicity, assume revenue generated from first month contract assumed up to month before the date the contract closes

```
Opp Start Date  OPP contract end date   Unique Account Field    MRR(expected)
1/2/2013         1/2/2015                 50e55                 195.00
1/2/2013         1/2/2014                 4ee75                 50.00
1/2/2013         1/2/2014                 4f031                 75.00
1/2/2013         1/2/2016                 4c3b2                 133.00
1/2/2013         1/2/2016                 49ec8                 132.00
1/3/2013         1/3/2014                 49fc8                 59.00
1/4/2013         1/4/2015                 49wc8                 87.00
12/27/2013       12/27/2014               50bf7                 190.00
12/27/2013       12/27/2014               49cc8                 179.00
12/27/2013       12/27/2014               49ec8                 147.00
```

etc....
I would like to calculate the following:

1. How much revenue was generated by month between Jan-2013 and Dec-2014?
2. How many active contracts (generated revenue in that month) were there by month between Jan-2013 and Dec-2014?
3. How many active accounts (generated revenue from at least one contract) were there by month between Jan-2013 and Dec-2014?

**I tried the below code:**
I was able to use sum() to get the revenues, but I'm not sure what to do beyond this.

```
from datetime import date
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Opp Start Date'])    
df.groupby(df['Opp Start Date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['MRR(expected)'].sum().sort_values()
```

Result I got from the above code:

```
Opp Start Date
February     221744
January      241268
July         245811
August       247413
April        249702
March        251219
June         251494
May          259149
September    263395
October      293990
November     296590
December     311659
```

I need to calculate the above following.
How can I achieve this in python?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: @jarlh SQL Server. I need to achieve this in either python/sql

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in either place, or a combination of the two. There are also lots of different ways you could approach this. Personally, I would create a query that pulled the information for one month, and then iterate through, either storing the results in an array or a temp table.

For a single month in the period, the query would look something like this:

```
Select count(unique_account_field), sum(MRR)
from contracts
where Opp_start_date <= @month_end
and Opp_contract_end_date > @month_start
```

That would take care of 1 and 2. #3 is a little different. That's a simple count(distinct unique_account_field) from the set over the whole period.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please elaborate #3. Like, if you able to provide sample query for #3 it would be really helpful. Can you pls look into this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70396117/sql-how-to-calculate-revenue-generated-in-each-month-in-sql

Comment: are you going to include the active account subquery